# Breaking out of shorthanded if statement

Tags: c++, c++11, if-statement, break, continue

I like to use shorthanded "if statements" of the format

**if-condition**?**then-statement**:**else-statement**

Whys is it that this works...

```
if (num==0)break;else continue;
```

And this doesn't?

```
num==4?break:continue;
```

Seeing as the two statements are logically equivalent.

Comment: Your question is based on a false premiss. The correct syntax is *if-condition ? expression : expression.*

Answer (score 0):

The first is a statement, the second is an expression. You cannot use statements in expressions.

The syntax of `if` is:

```
if (<expression>) <statement> [else <statement>]
```

The syntax of the expression is:

```
<Boolean expression> ? <expression> : <expression>
```

The syntax does not allow statements in an expression.

Comment: **−1** Rather than fixing this (which would have changed it beyond recognition) I just note that e.g. `42` is an expression, and `42;` is a statement.

Comment: @Cheers-and-hth-Alf, he still cannot have statements in expressions. I said nothing about turning expressions into statements. What's the downvote for?

Comment: Both are statements here. Its the `break` that can't be use as an operand of `?:` because `break` is a statement and this operator expects  expressions.

Comment: @haccks, ALL operators expect expressions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: First, the second is a statement, not an expression. Because it has a semicolon, which is the crucial difference. For example, `throw( "bah" )` is an expression that you can have in a conditional operator expression, while `throw( "bah" );` is a statement that you can't have there. An expression statement consists of an expression plus semicolon. Oh, one could write a book about this. :)

Comment: @anonymous upvoter: it's not a good idea to upvote incorrect information. that tends to spread the ungood meme.

Comment: @Cheers-and-hth-Alf, the info I gave is correct. Look at the depth of the syntax: the `?` can only be used in expressions and requires the `:` part. Within those parts there can only be other expressions and no statements. that's the crux of my answer. There is no syntactical construction to turn a statement into an expressions, though you can turn an expression into a statement with the semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: re " there can only be other expressions and no statements", that's irrelevant meaningless **nonsense**. The OP does not have statements in his expression. He does have keywords there.

Comment: @JayLord: You should not thank a man for teaching you nonsense things and arguing it when it's pointed out. He deserves thanks for trying to help you. But not for trying to convince people that he was right.